# Backyard gate not closing

Tags: doors, heat, backyard

With excessive heat this summer our backyard gate seems to have expanded and not closing. I'm requesting suggestions if I can do anything to fix it or is replacement the only solution.

[image]

Comment: Looks more like the post has slumped, if that bolt is meant to reach the metal plate.

Comment: It looks like maybe the building/one of the studs for the door frame sifted or the hinges holding the door are quite loose.

Comment: It's possible the gate itself has also "slumped."  Got any pics with more context?

Comment: Yeah, the problem isn't in this closeup view. Show is the whole situation.

Comment: Gates that don't fail do so because they're bolted to masonry, have an arbor above them, or both.

Comment: Hi yes seems like the door from the right has shifted I am unable to add pictures for some reason...should I create a new post

Answer (score 2):

Any wood, when exposed to the elements will twist, warp, expand and contract.

The hinge post may have twisted or slumped along with the bolts holding the hinges coming loose. The latch post may have moved as well.

This isn't a "do this" type of fix. There are probably a number of things that have moved or loosened to have this effect.  You will have to examine each  component and make adjustments as needed.

After finding the right alignment, you can look into adding diagonal bracing or turn-buckles to help keep things in place.  To tell you now to add this or that would be useless.